# Crashlytics: How to see user name/email/id in crash details?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics for collecting crashes from iOS app.
To make crash more specific I want to see user name/email/id in crash details.
For this goal I use such code:

```
[Crashlytics setUserIdentifier:@"userID"];
[Crashlytics setUserEmail:@"user@email.com"];
[Crashlytics setUserName:@"userName"];
```

When crash happens I cannot find a way to see this information in crash details.
I see such screen:
[image]

Question: How can I see user name/email/id in crash details?

Comment: Objective-C [Crashlytics setUserIdentifier:@"userID"];                                         Swift Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier("12345") . Where we can find those key values for setUserIdentifier?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is how I am doing it

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance.userIdentifier = (user) ? user : @"Unknown";
Crashlytics.sharedInstance.userName = (firstName && lastName) ? [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", firstName, lastName] : @"Anonymous";
```

I am doing it once when the user data is available.
Shows up in Fabric like this (when viewing details for a single crash): [image]

### UPDATE

- > [CrashlyticsKit setUserIdentifier:@"123456789"];
- > [CrashlyticsKit setUserEmail:@"person@domain.com"];
- > [CrashlyticsKit setUserName:@"Awesome AppUser"];

[Enhance Crash Reports](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#user-identifiers-in-objective-c)

Comment: Where we can find userIdentifier value?

Answer (score 11):

It's now in the bottom of a issue page under section 'Recent Activity'

[image]

Click into a version, you will see the more specific information. And the user information.

[image]

But there is another question, the crash and error was logged in Fabric is organized by group, and I have tested that a crash report can only record the recently triggered user information if a new user triggered this crash the user's information will replace the existing one.

> Update
>   I have asked for Twitter's support and found what I need. In issue list an issue item may combined with some same crashes or errors, in other word an item contains some crashes all in one. So a page represent a crash happened and detail information will display in it.**THE MOST IMPORTANT IS** the report can be scroll through in the top of the page then you can find the specific user information.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to see the user info.

Comment: @Jitendra Possibly crash happened before you set *userIdentifier*  or *userName*.

Or even before your app get username.

Also please select app version which contains username sending functionality as shown on first picture of this post.

Comment: No, I am crashing app after setting up the user identifier

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was no such option to see user name and details as it is but in issue details page there is a tab for `Export Ids` So on clicking same it downloads the `.csv` file of users.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I was able to see the user's information via pressing "View all sessions" from the Crashlytics dashboard.

[image: View all sessions button]

The user information should be shown on the following screen (bottom right):

[image: Test user info]

Comment: Have you set this 'setUserIdentifier' somewhere in your app?

Comment: @BharatModi Yes, I did it in viewDidLoad in a random view controller before logging any analytics, but you should set the user identifier typically after the user logs in.

Comment: Yes, i have added 'setUserIdentifier' when user logs in and now able to see the user details on crash but strangely i'm also able to see the user details for old builds versions. Don't know how it is happening.